# Time saved in DB as localtime instead UTC if i set time via django-admin panel

Tags: python, django-admin

I'm a little confused. I don't know why, but i think django saves time incorrectly in database when i set time to model in django-admin panel.
I have a USE_TZ=True and TIME_ZONE='UTC" settings but anyway it saves as my local time. If i'm manipulating with model instances via backend it saves time correctly in UTC. 
Hereis a picture where you can see i've set time through "Now" button in django-admin panel and it is saved the same time in DB as local time(which is not correct). But, at the same time my backend code saved another column time as UTC, which is correct. Why is it happening? I can't figure out how to save UTC in DB when using django admin-panel?

[image]